# react-native-google-places ERROR making places detection api call: ERROR

Tags: android, react-native, google-places-api, google-places

this is the code that the docs in the googleplace but  this is happend

**ERROR making places detection api call: ERROR**

```
  RNGooglePlaces.getCurrentPlace()
    .then((results) => alert(results))
    .catch((error) => alert(error.message));
```

Comment: What is the actual error you see?

Comment: ERROR making places detection api call: ERROR

Answer (score 0):

According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/tolu360/react-native-google-places/issues/83), assuming you're using [tolu360's react-native-google-places library](https://github.com/tolu360/react-native-google-places), you should check the following:

- Ensure device's GPS location is on.
- Ensure you have asked for (and received) `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission.
- Ensure you are using a real device, not an emulator.

Since you need a specific place, you need a real device with the ability to report it's location, and permission to access that information!

On [line 363 of RNGooglePlacesModule.java](https://github.com/tolu360/react-native-google-places/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/arttitude360/reactnative/rngoogleplaces/RNGooglePlacesModule.java) inside the library, you can add a breakpoint to see the actual error returned by `likelyPlaces.getStatus()`. I suggest you do this and add any extra information into your question.

Comment: @AllenCris Have added a further step for you.